# How to compute $ \displaystyle I(y)=\int_{0}^y\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^ke^{-a_i\cdot x-b_i}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^me^{-a_i \cdot x-b_i}}dx $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

How to compute the integral below?

$$
I(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i} + \sum_{i=k+1}^{m} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i}} \; dx
$$

where $a_i \geq 0$, $b_i \geq 0$, $1\leq k < m$.

Background:

I tried solving it using Taylor series expansion.
$$
I(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{m} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i}} \; dx \\
I(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i}}{e^{-a_j \cdot x -b_j}(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} e^{-(a_i - a_j) \cdot x - (b_i -b_j)} + \sum_{i=j+1}^{m} e^{-(a_i - a_j) \cdot x - (b_i -b_j)})} \; dx
$$

I have assumed, there exists $a_j$ and $b_j$ such that $(a_i - a_j) \geq 0$, and $(b_i - b_j) \geq 0$.
Substituting $a_l = a_i - a_j$, and $b_l = b_i - b_j$, I get
$$
I(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{k} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i})e^{a_j \cdot x +b_j}}{1 + \sum_{l=1}^{m-1} e^{-a_l \cdot x - b_l}} \; dx
$$
$$
I(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{k} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i})e^{a_j \cdot x +b_j}}{1 - (-\sum_{l=1}^{m-1} e^{-a_l \cdot x - b_l})} \; dx
$$
Using Taylor Series Expansion ,I get
$$
I(y) = \int_{0}^{y} (\sum_{i=1}^{k} e^{-a_i \cdot x - b_i})e^{a_j \cdot x +b_j} \cdot \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (\sum_{l=1}^{m-1} e^{-a_l \cdot x - b_l})^{n} \right) \; dx
$$

Is there any method to complete this computation of the integral?

Any help will be appreciated.